# Phonegap. What happens to web SQL database on app update?

Tags: cordova, web-sql

Please excuse the very novice question but I am about to embark on my first mobile app project using Phonegap. My project will rely heavily on a web SQL database. When I make updates to the app in the future, I need the database the user has built up to remain intact. I would assume the database is contained within the app package, When they update, what happens to the database? is it completely reset with the new app?

(I've spent quite sometime googling this but have not found an answer to my query)

Comment: :I am using the same tools (phonegap,cordova & web-sql) but struggling with asynch call issue. Can you help or suggest anything with your experience,please? I have put my details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402597/page-before-database-phonegap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will remain as it is (except the iOS 5.1 bug which is already resolved - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-347)

You can also test and produce the same scenario by upgrading the application in your simulator or your device and see the result.

Check more detail in this post - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/NhPTwzi4KnU

Comment: Just the info I was looking for. Thank you