# localStorage Persistent through App Store Update iOS 8

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, local-storage

Similar questions to this have been asked, however, they are either a couple years old or the answers are not complete.

I am wondering if with iOS 7/8 and Cordova 3.7+ for iOS the `localStorage` from a hybrid app would persist through an App Store update?

The reason that I ask, is that I would like to save a small array of user preferences and I would like them to persist through app updates.

if `localStorage` does not persist, are there alternatives that will persist?

Thanks.

Comment: In android localstorage is not persist if app is update

Comment: If localstorage does not persist as per @shammon then you could use `sqlite` aka `WebSQL`. The sqlite should persists across updates. Look [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) for `WebSQL` documentation. Also have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278841/phonegap-what-happens-to-web-sql-database-on-app-update) for confirmation of persistance across updates regarding `WebSQL`