# PouchDB with Ionic and App updates

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am currently building an app using Ionic framework with AngularJS, and PouchDB for local database storage.

For now the data is only stored locally on PouchDB, and is not synced online.

My question is. When I update the iOS or Android app to a newer version, will the user-generated content be removed from PouchDB, or is the update merging seamlessly?

Comment: since you define the database in your code, why would it change?

Comment: When the app is launched there will be some data included (seeder). I'm worried about the extra content, that the user will save in the database.

Will the database be written over (replaced) when updating the app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278841/phonegap-what-happens-to-web-sql-database-on-app-update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the local data is not removed when the app updates.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for the answer Nolan.