# ionic storage on App update

Tags: ionic-framework, storage, ionic3

I searched over and over but could not find and answer to this:

1. What happens to local storage (Used by high level storage class of Ionic 2/3 ) when updating the app?

I saw that when reinstalling it is removed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same and found a link in which they claim that localStorage is not reliable, you should always use ionic native storage plugin.

[Original post](https://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/)

It says that IOS clears localStorage when memory is low, and contains a link for android uses that reports inconsistencies too.

The safest bet is to always use [ionic-storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)

**Edit**

If you uninstall and reinstall the app, when you do that, it will clear all app data, including local DBs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is what I meant - using the class Storage (ionic-storage) , which is an higher implementation ( which uses "the best available options" as it states) . So using this class, the local data is saved on app updates???

Comment: my bad, i see what you're saying, well by reinstall, did you just updated it or uninstalled, if you do the latter data will be lost.

Comment: Update  i did not tried- my client need some fixes and I want to make sure the local data of the users will not be lost

Comment: So you say it wont be lost -both on android and IOS? no matter what?

Comment: You can test it in a simulator, old app, some data, and upgrade it. Also check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282966/1303897

Comment: Cool, please come back to this post with your results, upvote and accept if it worked.